# Timezone in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a column `time_stamp` of type `timestamp without time zone`.

While executing `select now()::timestamp(0)` it returns a value with PST timezone. But my system timezone is IST.

I need the same in PostgreSQL output. Please anyone help me to fix it.

Comment: Please provide your code and where you're stuck with proper error message.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. I edited postgresql conf file. Now i got desired output.

Comment: If you have fixed it already, u might consider posting the answer here. I t might help someone in future.